# implement each method in user class which has extend ActiveRecord::Base

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Redefine `each` methods in `ActiveRecord::Base` for spec class `User`

This is what i know

```
class Rainbow
 include Enumerable
  def each
   yield "red"
   yield "orange"
   yield "yellow"
   yield "green"
   yield "blue"
   yield "indigo"
   yield "violet"
  end
end

r = Rainbow.new

r.select { |a| a.start_with?('r')} #=> ["red"]
```

**Ok !!**

Like this way what i want in `User Model`

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
  include Enumerable
   def user_ids
    User.all.map(&:id)   ## instead of this i want to write like User.map(&:id) 
   end 
  end
```

Actually There is lots of data in `News model` and in need only `id` from all the record To write the query like `User.all.map(&:id)` it taking lots of time.

**1:** For that i need to redefine `each method` but how ? but what line of codes i need to write in each method .

**2:** so that all the enumerable method can invoke on that classe`s object

Is there any other way.

Any help would be greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a good idea. The reason is because ActiveRecord classes (and therefore inner instance methods) can be both accessed as first-class object (when you call `Model.foo`) or via the `ActiveRecord::Relation` object and association proxy.

There is a very high chance that you will cause some hard-to-detect conflict at some point.

There is no real benefit of trying to do what you want to do. In fact, the method

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
  include Enumerable

  def user_ids
    User.all.map(&:id)
  end 
end
```

can already be rewritten to

```
def user_ids
  User.ids
end
```

that is a shorter version for

```
def user_ids
  User.pluck(:id)
end
```

Note that both `pluck` and `ids` selects only the required field, hence they are way more efficient (both at Ruby level and at database level) than loading all the records and mapping a field.

Without mentioning that your code is probably wrong. In fact, you are defining an instance method that should be called

```
User.new.user_ids
```

whereas you probably expect to use it as

```
User.user_ids
```

hence you can define it as

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 

  def self.user_ids
    # User it's implicit, its the current scope
    ids
  end 
end
```

You can define `each`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
  include Enumerable

  def each(&block)
    # all returns a lazy-evaluated scope
    # that responds to each
    # Note that .each will trigger a query.
    # In this case, that's effectively equivalent to to_a.each
    all.each(&block)
  end 
end
```

but it will not bring you any advantage. Moreover, that will always trigger a query at the time you call the method, skipping the very handy lazy-load feature of active record.

In fact, `ActiveRecord::Relation` exists also as a performance improvement to take advantage of lazy-load.

---

Bottom line, if your goal is to not type `User.all.map(&:id)` then use a custom method, or use the Rails API effectively.

```
User.all.map(&:id)
```

can be written as

```
User.pluck(:id)
```

which is equivalent to

```
User.ids
```

that wrapped in a method becomes

```
class User
  def self.user_ids
    ids
  end
end

User.user_ids
```